# Why is Firechat not initializing?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Firechat is an "open-source real-time chat, built on Firebase." You may find its source code [here](https://github.com/firebase/firechat).

I am trying to initialize Firechat after authenticating the user, but the chat will not initialize. I get no errors on the console. This is the code (there is no CSS). I usually register a user first and then try to login with it.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <!-- Firebase -->
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.1.0/firebase.js'></script>

    <!-- Firechat -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firechat/2.0.1/firechat.min.css' />
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firechat/2.0.1/firechat.min.js'></script>


    <script src='authentication.js'></script>


</head>
<body>

<section class="container">
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Login to Chat</h1>
      <form>
        <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username" id="loginUsername"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="loginPassword"></p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login" onclick='login();'></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>


<section class="container">
    <div class="register">
      <h1>Register on Chat</h1>
      <form>
        <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username" id="registerUsername"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="registerPassword"></p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Register" onclick='register();'></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>


    <div id='firechat-wrapper'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
// Create a new Firebase reference, and a new instance of the Login client
var chatRef = new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/');

// Create new user

function register() {
    var username = document.getElementById("registerUsername").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("registerPassword").value;
    chatRef.createUser({
        email    : username,
        password : password
    }, function(error, userData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error creating user:", error);
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
        }
    });

}

// Login user

function login() {
    var username = document.getElementById("loginUsername").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("loginPassword").value;
    chatRef.authWithPassword({
        email    : username,
        password : password
    }, function(error, authData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
        } else {
            console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
        }
    });

    chatRef.onAuth(function(authData) {
  // Once authenticated, instantiate Firechat with the user id and user name
  if (authData) {
    initChat(authData);
  }
});

}


function initChat(authData) {
  var chat = new FirechatUI(chatRef, document.getElementById('firechat-wrapper'));
  chat.setUser(authData.uid, authData[authData.provider].displayName);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems that I see in the code above, which after fixing, allowed this demo to work on my local machine:

1. The field names in the forms are named `login` and `register`, which can cause conflicts with your method names. Try renaming the `login` and `register` methods to `loginUser` and `registerUser` to avoid any potential conflicts with elements in the form.
2. The form submissions currently cause the page to navigate away from the current page and quick "refresh", meaning that you're never fully completing the account creation or login. To solve this, add a `return false;` after invoking the target method in your `onclick` handler. For example, `<input type='submit' ... onclick='registerUser();return false;'>`.
3. The `onAuth(function(authData) {...})` event listener is only attached during user login, so on page refresh you'll miss picking up persisted sessions. Try attaching it right away, so that you'll automatically instantiate Firechat if the user is already authenticated.

Updated code below:

**JS**:

```
// Create a new Firebase reference, and a new instance of the Login client
var isInitialized = false;
var chatRef = new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/');
chatRef.onAuth(function(authData) {
  // Once authenticated, instantiate Firechat with the user id and user name
  if (authData && !isInitialized) {
    initChat(authData);
  }
});

// Create new user
function registerUser() {
  var username = document.getElementById("registerUsername").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("registerPassword").value;
  chatRef.createUser({
    email    : username,
    password : password
  }, function(error, userData) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Error creating user:", error);
    } else {
      console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
    }
  });
  return false;
}

// Login user
function loginUser() {
  var username = document.getElementById("loginUsername").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("loginPassword").value;
  chatRef.authWithPassword({
    email    : username,
    password : password
  }, function(error, authData) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Login Failed!", error);
    } else {
      console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
    }
  });
  return false;
}


function initChat(authData) {
  var chat = new FirechatUI(chatRef, document.getElementById('firechat-wrapper'));
  chat.setUser(authData.uid, authData.uid);
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <!-- Firebase -->
  <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.1.0/firebase.js'></script>

  <!-- Firechat -->
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firechat/2.0.1/firechat.min.css' />
  <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firechat/2.0.1/firechat.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

  <section class="container">
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Login to Chat</h1>
      <form>
        <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username" id="loginUsername"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="loginPassword"></p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login" onclick='loginUser();return false;'></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>


  <section class="container">
    <div class="register">
      <h1>Register on Chat</h1>
      <form>
        <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username" id="registerUsername"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="registerPassword"></p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Register" onclick='registerUser();return false;'></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div id='firechat-wrapper'></div>
  <script src='authentication.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Rob - this worked perfectly. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Hi again Rob - maybe you would be able to guide me through solving this other problem. After authenticating the user, FireChat does initialize, but it is missing key features in the chat (http://oi58.tinypic.com/2cqgubm.jpg). I have been reading over the API docs but cannot figure out how the different FireChat methods interact with the #firechat-wrapper in the html. I may be approaching this whole issue in the wrong way. Also, if this helps, when I create a room in the chat it gives the following error: "FIREBASE WARNING: set at /room-metadata/-JwRsGpD1VLJv0XlXzKG failed: permission_denied"

Comment: Rob - I figured it out. It was a problem with my rules.

Comment: just asked a new question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953666/firebase-change-remember-property-dynamically-when-authenticating