# Firebase - change remember property dynamically when authenticating

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a checkbox input in my html which the user can check if he/she wishes to stay logged into the app after the browser has been closed. I would like to change between remember: "default", and remember: "sessionOnly" depending on whether the user checks the box or not.

This is my function to check whether the box in the html is checked or not:

```
function checkLoginTerm() {
    var result;
    if(document.getElementById('#loginkeeping').checked) {
        result = "sessionOnly";
    } else {
        result =  "default";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then I call the function in my login function to be executed after the user authenticates like this:

```
function loginUser(username, password) {
    if (checkVariable(username)) {var username = document.getElementById("loginUsername").value;}
    if (checkVariable(password)) {var password = document.getElementById("loginPassword").value;}
    firebaseRef.authWithPassword({
        email    : username,
        password : password
    }, function(error, authData) {
        if (error) {
            alert("Login Failed! "+ error, error);
        } else {
            console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
        }

    }, {
        remember: checkLoginTerm()
    });
}
```

If I do this, the login process will never complete. But if I put the appropriate string directly after remember: (for example remember: "sessionOnly"), it will do what its told.

Comment: Have you checked your error log? There's almost certainly an error being thrown when your code cannot find the `#loginkeeping` element, since the element id is probably `loginkeeping` (without the `#`). The `#` is used by jQuery convention for generic DOM selectors.

Comment: such a silly mistake! There were no errors on the console though :( maybe something about the cache? I'm still having some trouble implementing the solution above with the id in the correct format for some reason. The login process will work but it will keep the user logged in no matter what.

Comment: aha! wait, seems like I had messed the order in my conditional within the function. I must be tired...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Rob DiMarco in the comments below my question, there were two minor issues -

1. The id of the element is loginkeeping and not #loginkeeping
2. I had made a logic error in the conditional statement within my checkLoginTerm() function